# Neo4J OGM - session.save() Method Does Not Update When Delete Relationships From Entities

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

session.save() method in the main2 does not update connected sub nodes. Removed node "tn2" is still connected with "to" via "tn1".

Neo4J 3.1.0 and Neo4J OGM 2.1.2 with Bolt configuration.

Here are the example of code;

```
@NodeEntity
public class TestOrg {
@GraphId
private Long id;

@Relationship(type="ROOT", Direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
TestNode rn;
}

public class TestNode {
@GraphId
private Long id;

@Relationship(type="HAS", Direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
List<TestNode> subs = new ArrayList<TestNode>();

//remove method: gets the name of the node and removes from the subs list.
}

main1{
TestNode tn1 = new TestNode();
tn1.setName("tn1");

TestNode tn2 = new TestNode();
tn2.setName("tn2");

TestNode tn3 = new TestNode();
tn3.setName("tn3");

tn1.addSub(tn2);
tn1.addSub(tn3);

TestOrg to = new TestOrg();
to.setName("to");
to.setRn(t1);
session.save(to);
}

main2{
...
//gets the id of the TestOrg with name "to" from db

TestOrg to = session.load(TestOrg.class, id, maxDepth); 

to.getRn().remove("tn2"); 

session.save(to, maxDepth); //session.save(to) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've most probably not removed the reference for "tn2" from both sides. 
`to.getRn().remove("tn2")` removes the reference from the TestNode, but nothing removes it from the TestOrg. Try adding `to.setRn(null)` and it should work